# How do the folk at wildfly intend for one to manage database datasources in a sensible way now that xxx-ds.xml files are deprecated?

Tags: jboss, datasource, wildfly

We make a lot of web applications which have been using various iterations of wildfly née jboss.  We nearly always make use of databases and JNDI accessible datasources for the database connections which we have traditionally deployed by means of a xxx-ds.xml file in the deployments folder.  These auto deployed -ds.xml files have been useful in the past as and when we've had to make changes or deploy applications programmatically etc.

Since Wildfly 8 or 9 there's been a deprecation warning for this method of setting up datasources.  The wildfly documentation pretty much exclusively talks about using the management web interface (Something that is generally witched off once a project goes live).  So using this is not practical or desirable for us.  With that in mind, how should we (potentially pro grammatically via shell scripts) continue to set up and configure datasources?

Comment: Please give you're feedback on the JIRA https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4296. It can always be undeprecated if there is enough response :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the web interface for this, you can edit your standalone.xml (or whichever version you are using) file and add the datasources you need.

Example:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:3.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS"
            enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/postgresExample" pool-name="postgresExample"
            enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgresExample</connection-url>
            <driver>postgres</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                <password>postgres</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="postgres" module="org.postgresql">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

I know is not as good as deploying the datasource, maybe someone has a better answer!

Comment: Sorry for posting this comment twice, but I think it's important to get all the feedback we can. Please give you're feedback on the JIRA https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4296. It can always be undeprecated if there is enough response :)

Comment: WRT to the actual answer. You can use CLI to add a data-source as well. Here's an example script https://gist.github.com/jamezp/3d3fe3bf57fe99ea91c1